# Can you access AD if your credentials are correct, but the machine is not in the group?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, active-directory

I am writing a program in which the user authenticates himself through Active Directory, and if he is in the correct group, allow him to proceed and do xyz.
Now, the question is, if the user, who is in the correct group, has the right credentials and rights, can authenticate/access Active Directory, if he logs on a computer which is in a different AD group? I use C# to program this and am using `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

Currently, I connect through `LDAP://OU=Users,OU=name1,OU=name2,OU=name3,DC=dc1,DC=dc2,DC=com` and pass the path along with the username and password to the connection.

The users are all stored in a directory, but I do not know if it is even possible to use the other path if the above fails, or if the computer can access it (if he is in the wrong group).

What happens if the program is on a server, and a user starts the program from a computer, that has the rights to access the .exe on the server, but is in a different group than above, or not in a group at all?

Comment: By default all domain users have read permissions (this permission comes from Authenticated users security principal). So connection succeeds. The best practice here is to run program under the service account with sufficient permissions, validate user credentials and check if the user is in correct group. This part can be implemented as as service, which your program connects to. The simple way is to connect to ad with user credentials, and check if he is in the correct group but it is not recommended

Comment: What do you mean by "a computer in a different AD group"?  Are you sure you mean "group" and not, say, "domain" or "forest" or "site"?  Computers *can* be put into groups, but by default they are only in "Domain Computers".  The computer's group membership should have no effect on user authentication.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, sorry, I meant forest, trying to translate and we name it differently here. But I think I solved this myself by altering the connection, since you can specify the IP and direct path to the domain.